# simple linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = kx$, $x(0) = 10$. What does the graph of the solution look like (two cases needed: $k>0$ and $k<0$)?

Thanks.

Comment: use separation of variables.

Comment: I don't know how to do the first part, but the second part is going to be a parabola open downward or upward depending on K (negative or positive value)

Comment: Can i just take integration of both parts, where the right side is going to be kx^2+c ( since k is a constant ) and plug in x(0)m where it's going to give us the value of c, have no clue how is that related but that's all i can think about

Comment: dx/x = kdt
ln|x| = kt + c
x = ±e^(kt + c)
x = ±e^(c) * e^(kt)
x = ae^(kt)

Its an exponential. Where a is some arbitrary constant
Whether its decaying or growing depends on k.

Comment: When you said separation of variables i didn't think of that, thanks. But is it correct?

Comment: Could those voting to close please tell the OP *why* they consider this question to be "too localised"? In general, this is code for "OP needs to show more effort", but that is clearly not the case here...

Comment: @Zack sorry I didn't get back to earlier. I guess you see what I meant now given the nice answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{kx}&=dt\\
\int \frac{dx}{x}&=k\int dt\\
\log(x)&=kt+c_1\\
ce^{kt}&=x
\end{align*}

Taking $t=0$
$$10e^{kt}=x$$
To understand the graph, study the limiting behaviour as t approaches infinity.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir, that helped a lot.